# My own picture as building in google maps sdk

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

If I have a building and of course know it's coordinates how can I replace/cover this building with my own picture? Is it even possible? I want to achieve something like that:
[image]

to:
[image]

Ofcourse it's just an example. I've already tried marker but if marker is big and the building has some text like "National Bank" it can't be placed (at least I couldn't) on the text.

Comment: Have you looked at [Ground Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/groundoverlay)?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!